# list_filter triggering a FieldError

Tags: django, django-models

One of my queries suddenly started to fail after I made some changes to the AdminModel.

After searching a bit, I found that adding a list_filter to my admin_model is creating the FieldError, which seems really strange to me...

My models:

```
class PiafInfo( models.Model ):
    no = models.IntegerField( u'No du Piaf', unique=True )
    origin_city = models.ForeignKey( City )
    ...

class PiafInfoAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    list_display = ('no', 'origin_city', 'group', 'fleet')
    list_filter = ['origin_city', ]
    ordering = ('no',)
    search_fields = ('no', 'group', 'fleet') 
admin.site.register( PiafInfo, PiafInfoAdmin )

class PiafTrans( models.Model ):
    ttype         = models.IntegerField( choices=TTYPE_CHOICES, default=TTYPE_RELOAD)
    date          = models.DateTimeField()
    piafSerial    = models.ForeignKey( PiafInfo )
    ...

class PiafTransAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'piafSerial', 'city', 'ttype', 'amount', 'subscrName' )
    date_hierarchy = 'date'
    list_filter = ('city', 'ttype')
    search_fields = ('piafSerial', 'group', 'fleet', 'subscrName' ) 
admin.site.register( PiafTrans, PiafTransAdmin )
```

The query posing problem (second line) :

```
piafInfos = models.PiafInfo.objects.all().distinct()
piafInfos = piafInfos.filter( piaftrans__date__range=(startDate,endDate) ).distinct()
```

Like that, I get the following error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'piaftrans' into field. Choices are: fleet, group, id, no, origin_city
```

It tries to interpret piaftrans as a field name instead of a model.

If I comment a single line in PiafInfoAdmin:

```
class PiafInfoAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    list_display = ('no', 'origin_city', 'group', 'fleet')
    # list_filter = ['origin_city', ]
    ordering = ('no',)
    search_fields = ('no', 'group', 'fleet') 

admin.site.register( PiafInfo, PiafInfoAdmin )
```

The error disappears. I don't see any correlation between the error and the change I made!

This is with django 1.3 and Python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. Hadn't read your question with enought attention. Sorry.

Comment: Not sure about your error, but your first `piafInfos = models.PiafInfo.objects.all().distinct()` seems redundant since you could combine the two calls and use only one. Try using `models.PiafInfo.objects.filter( piaftrans__date__range=(startDate,endDate) ).distinct()`

Comment: I'll do some more testing with different versions to see if anything pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce here. Using
models.py:

```
class City( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=110)

class PiafInfo( models.Model ):
    no = models.IntegerField( u'No du Piaf', unique=True )
    origin_city = models.ForeignKey( City )

class PiafTrans( models.Model ):
    ttype         = models.IntegerField()
    date          = models.DateTimeField()
    piafSerial    = models.ForeignKey( PiafInfo )
```

admin.py:

```
class PiafInfoAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    list_display = ('no', 'origin_city',)
    list_filter = ['origin_city', ]
    ordering = ('no',)
    search_fields = ('no',) 
admin.site.register( PiafInfo, PiafInfoAdmin )

class PiafTransAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'piafSerial', 'ttype', )
    date_hierarchy = 'date'
    list_filter = ('ttype')
    search_fields = ('piafSerial', )
admin.site.register( PiafTrans, PiafTransAdmin )
```

django 1.3.8 pre-alfa (latest from 1.3 branch)

and the following code:

```
startDate = datetime.today()
endDate = datetime.today()
piafInfos = PiafInfo.objects.all().distinct()
piafInfos = piafInfos.filter( piaftrans__date__range=(startDate,endDate) ).distinct()
```